# PostgreSQL drivers are not enabled in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

When I launch Geoserver (v.2.24.0) and try to create new User Group Service with JDBC connection, there is not any PostgreSQL drivers available:

[image: No Postgresql drivers]

This happens when I launch Geoserver **without** sample datasets. Easy workaround is just visit to visit 'Stores' and then drivers are available.

I presume some drivers are not "initialized" by default.

To repeat problem with docker containers, first launch docker container:

```
docker pull docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.0
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --env SKIP_DEMO_DATA=true docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.0
```

Access dockerized geoserver from http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ and user default admin/geoserver to login.

Go to Security => Users, Groups, Roles

[image: Security => Users, Groups, Roles]

Add new User Group Service:

[image: new User Group Service]

Click JDBC connection:

[image: JDBC connection]

And you see that PostgreSQL drivers are not enabled.

Comment: Bug reports like this should go directly to the project - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/boards/8

Comment: I was too shy to create bug, now it has been reported: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-11211